# Debugging jQuery AJAX response: what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging, json

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'place/add',
    data: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        name: name,
        address: address,
        phone: phone,
        review: review,
        category: category
    },
    success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    alert(data.id);
    // ......
});
```

The first alert gives:`{"id":"2","success":true}`, but the second: `undefined`

Answer (score 11):

You need to specify your anticipated returned data type as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json', // specifies the return type
    url: 'place/add',
    data: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        name: name,
        address: address,
        phone: phone,
        review: review,
        category: category
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        alert(data.id);
        // ......
    }
});
```

Comment: Other valid return types include **xml**, **html**, **script**, **jsonp**, and **text**.  The default return type is *html or xml*, so it is best to specify your required returnType to avoid the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

An especially useful addition, if you run multiple ajax calls is $.ajaxSetup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Any subsequent ajax calls will use these as the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `dataType: 'json'` or eval returned data yourself like this `var data = eval('(function(){return '+data+'})()');`

BTW trust jQuery - use `dataType: 'json'` if you can.